# Validating an AWS certificate on godday using CName

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate

I think I understand what the [docs from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html) is saying about this, but Godaddy doesn't seem to let me enter the valid information for the certificate validation, or I'm not looking at the right place.

I've requested the certificate using ACM allright. Now on GoDaddy, I'm trying to do the following:

[image]

This corresponds to CNAME name and CNAME value in ACM console manager:

[image]

Yet the interface in godaddy doesn't accept the input. Am I looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `name` field should be just the prefix of `AWS CNAME name`, for example:

```
_this-is-the-part-you-take.my-domain.com.
```

In other words, `_904706782abb3d16301321f28db53e03.my-domain.com.` get this `_904706782abb3d16301321f28db53e03`

and in the value, put the

```
_0ba986089fff81c1b4f395a2ea75f42e.example.acm-validations.aws
```

Turns out that AWS has a section on validation issues with godaddy. :)

[Check this out.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/dns-validation.html#troubleshooting-DNS-GoDaddy)

TLDR; Either ask godaddy what the valid entries should be or use email validation.

Comment: Hmm, that's what I did, but I get "Record could not be added". But that's where I should be looking, at least there's that. 

I am trying to add this record as a delegate for somelse's domain; could that be my issue? Or doesn'T matter if they added me as a delegate and I have access to DNS records, I should be able to add some, right?

Comment: I guess you should be able, but that's weird the record couldn't be added.

Comment: okay thanks I'll check with their tech support I update here, at least I know I'm broadly speaking doing the right higns. thanks

Comment: I've updated the answer, see if it helps. :)

Comment: Okay well tech support added it for me. When I asked why I couldn't do it, his answer was caching issues related to previous attemps. Should clear cache/log out. Dunno if that's actually it or not. Anyways It's been added now

Comment: How to add for subdomains, my domain got verified but my subdomain (www) is not verified